# How do I construct pairs of pants and morse functions on them?

Tags: differential-geometry, conformal-geometry, morse-theory

I'm learning about morse theory and one of the pictures that keeps popping up is that of a pair of pants. Unfortunately, these pairs of pants are only a doodle for me; I have no idea how to model these rigorously. In addition, I want to be able to use the height functor to analyse these objects. Where can I learn about these constructions?

Comment: I love the title of this question. Maybe more children would aspire to be mathematicians if they knew it would give them the ability to construct pairs of pants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a parametric model of a pair of pants by taking a torus and restricting to one half (letting the longitude vary from 0 to $\pi$, for example), and then restricting to points ... let me just write it out.

$$
X(u, v) = (   (2 + \cos v) \cos u ,   (2 + \sin v)  \sin u           , \sin v)
$$

Now restrict to points $-\frac{\pi}{2} \le u \le \frac{\pi}{2}$, and then restrict to points whose first coordinate is no greater than, say, $2.5$. The resulting shape is a pair of pants, and the first coordinate is a morse function on it.

Comment: This is great! I wanted to ask how I can do this for more general spaces, like the ones you see in pictures of TQFT; should this be in another question?

Comment: Yes, it should be another question. Writing "chameleon questions" (ones that keep changing as people provide answers) isn't considered nice. I should mention, though, that explicit parameterizations are worth having once or twice, but they often obscure the real point you want to look at. You can spend a lot of time screwing around differentiating complicated-looking formulas rather than realizing that the implicit function theorem tells you that locally you just have to look at $y = x_1^2 + \ldots + x_k^2 - x_{k+1}^2 - \ldots -x_n^2$, at least in a suitable coordinate system.